# Changing the visibility of an UserControl by PropertyChangedEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**Update**: Full working example:

I am using property binding to change the visibility of an usercontrol in my window. With the INotifyPropertyChanged i notify the UI to update.

I am using [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/) RelayCommand implementation.

C#

```
    //ViewModel:
    public class homeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       private Visibility _Home;
       public Visibility Home
       {
          get { return _Home; }
          set { 
                 if(_Home == value) return;
                 _Home = value;
                 PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Home"));
              }
       }

       public ICommand HideHomeCommand
       {
          get { 
              return new RelayCommand( 
                o => HideUserControl, 
                o => {return Home != Visibility.Collapsed;}
              );
          }
       }
       private void HideUserControl()
       {
          Home = Visibility.Collapse;
       }
       public ICommand ShowHomeCommand
       {
          get { 
              return new RelayCommand( 
                o => ShowUserControl, 
                o => {return Home != Visibility.Visible;}
              );
          }
       }
       private void ShowUserControl()
       {
          Home = Visibility.Visible;
       }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:homeViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Show Home" Command="{Binding ShowHomeCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Collapse Home" Command="{Binding HideHomeCommand}" />
        <views:home Visibility="{Binding Home }" /> 
        <!-- home is an usercontrol -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you bind visibility `Home` with `<views:home Visibility="{Binding Home}"/>` you should use:

`PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Home"));`

This way you invoke property changed event for `Home` property. Also there is no need for `_myHome` to be a property. It should be a simple private field.

There is a library called [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/) which handles all these property changed events automatically, you may want to look at it.

If you want to handle `PropertyChanged` events manually and you are using C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015), you may want to use:

`PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Home)));`.

With previous code if you rename `Home` property and forget to change the string in `PropertyChanged` event it will silently fail to notify. But with this code the compilation will fail and you will have to fix it.

Comment: You're right. _myHome should be private. I've the problem that i need a customized setter of home (to send notify) but if i return Home in the getter of home i got an invinity loop (says vs) therefore i have the second _myHome.

Comment: Yes that's the way to use it. Only that `_myHome` does not need to be a property. You can define it like `private Visibility _myHome;`

Comment: YES. Fody is a great library. I can highly recommend it. I can also recommend using WPF inspector. It's a standalone application, that allows you to attach it you your debugging application, and inspect everything in it. Update values in the inspector and watch it update in your UI. Makes life easier to detect not bound elements or wrong binding modes.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code and the question. But that dont solve my problem. Anyone can explain that issue? - I'll check my app with WPF Inspector and give you a feedback.

Comment: There is more to this question. With the code you provided I can successfully collapse and show the control. Please provide the actual code so I can see what is wrong.